# Adjust title font size for a Bokeh figure

Tags: python, bokeh

How do I set the title font size for a figure when using bokeh?

I tried (in ipython notebook):

```
import bokeh.plotting as bp
import numpy as np
bp.output_notebook()

x_points = np.random.rand(100)
y_points = np.random.rand(100)

bp.figure(title='My Title', x_axis_label='X axis', y_axis_label='Y axis', \
    text_font_size='8pt')

bp.scatter(x_points, y_points)
bp.show()
```

I've tried text_font_size, label_text_font, title_font_size, etc.
Where in the documentation is all of this information?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I figured it out. You need to prepend 'title_' to 'text_font_size'

```
import bokeh.plotting as bp
import numpy as np
bp.output_notebook()

x_points = np.random.rand(100)
y_points = np.random.rand(100)

bp.figure(title='My Title', x_axis_label='X axis', y_axis_label='Y axis', \
    title_text_font_size='8pt')

bp.scatter(x_points, y_points)
bp.show()
```

Comment: Why does `bokeh` require fontsize to have `pt` on it?

Comment: You gave to use this style                                                              
p2.title.text_font_size = "50pt"  where p2 was p2 was defined as a figure

Answer (score 33):

Plot property `title_text_font_size` was [deprecated in 0.12.5](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.12.10/docs/releases/0.12.5.html) and will be removed. As of bokeh version 0.12.0, [one should use](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/basic/annotations.html#titles) `Plot.title.text_font_size` instead. Updated example is below:

```
import numpy as np
import bokeh.plotting as bp

bp.output_notebook()

x_points = np.random.rand(100)
y_points = np.random.rand(100)

p = bp.figure(title='My Title', x_axis_label='X axis', y_axis_label='Y axis')

p.title.text_font_size = '8pt'

p.scatter(x_points, y_points)
bp.show(p)
```

You can change the font size of axis labels similarly:

```
p.xaxis.axis_label_text_font_size = "20pt"
p.yaxis.axis_label_text_font_size = "20pt"
```